# Problem with Quarkus Dependency Injection to JPA Entity Manager

Tags: jpa, cdi, quarkus

Problem with the build

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: 
Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems: 
[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManager and qualifiers [@DataSource(value = "ergoint")]
    - java member: com.int.dao.EPersistence#entityManagerE
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[java.lang.Object, com.int.dao.EPersistence], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.int.dao.EPersistence]
[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManager and qualifiers [@DataSource(value = "madata")]
    - java member: com.int.dao.MPersistence#entityManagerM
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.int.dao.MasterDataPersistence, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.int.dao.MPersistence]
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:873)
```

Code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MPersistence {

    @Inject
    @DataSource("madata")
    private EntityManager entityManagerMaster;
```

Properties file:

```
quarkus.datasource.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

quarkus.datasource.madata.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl
quarkus.datasource.madata.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.madata.username=quarkus_test
quarkus.datasource.madata.password=quarkus_test
```

Simply run "maven clean install" from eclipse ide and get this issue while running test case.

(Earlier i think these two classes were readable with @Stateless from EJB but when i update quarkus to 1.1.0 final it removed all EJB dependencies. So i put application scoped)

Comment: So if you use eclipselink instead of hibernate it works? (The entitymanager interface is JPA, not Hibernate)

Comment: quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver is wrong this must be quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect But if that is the problem I don't know

Comment: I'm no quarkus user but it looks like there are multiple beans eligeable to for injection due to the `[types=[com.int.dao.MasterDataPersistence, java.lang.Object]` way they are described in the error. Weld would explicitly state so, maybe Quarkus does not. Might be that one is for production and one for test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: since Quarkus 1.8, we support setting up several persistence units directly in the application.properties. See https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#multiple-persistence-units for more information.

We do not support multiple persistence units configured in the `application.properties` yet.
Thus the `EntityManager`s you try to inject are not created by Quarkus.

You can track this issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2835 to be notified of our progress on the subject .

Comment: Is it still not support?

Comment: It is supported since Quarkus 1.8.